# Fetch arrays of values in CoreData

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, core-plot

In my **XCode** project, I have two entities for my CoreData.  These entities are called **Session** and **SessionDetails**.  Session has one attribute called `timeCompleted (Type: Date)` which is a time stamp of the event.  Session is in a one-to-many relationship to SessionDetails but the attribute that is most important is `averageDistance (Type: Float)`.

The Sessions are sorted using timeCompleted.  I would like to fetch the averageDistance values of the sorted Sessions and place them in an array that could be used to generate a plot.  The x-axis will have the date of the event and the y-axis will have the averageDistance value.  I am not concerned right now with creating the plot but rather just extracting the values that will be used for it.  Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Is averageDistance a property of Session or of the related SessionDetails entity?

Comment: Indeed — is there a one-to-one relationship between `Session` and the `averageDistance` property (in which case you can use key-value coding directly on the array of sessions) or is `SessionDetails` implicated somehow, making a one-to-many relationship?

Comment: Unless I was mistaken when I created the relationships, it was given a one-to-many relationship since another attribute in SessionDetails could have many values (distanceValue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Key-Value coding to get an array of attribute values. Assuming that
`averageDistance` is an attribute of *Session*, you can do the following:

```
NSArray *sessions = ...; // Your sorted array of Session objects
NSArray *distValues = [sessions valueForKey:@"averageDistance"];
```

`distValues` is now an array of `NSNumber` objects containing the `averageDistance` from each Session object.

**UPDATE:** As it turned out in the discussion,
there is a to-many relationship from *Session* to *SessionDetails*, `averageDistance`
is an attribute of *SessionDetails*, and
 you need all possible `(timeCompleted, averageDistance)` pairs, sorted by `timeCompleted`.

Therefore, you should fetch all
*SessionDetails* objects instead of fetching *Session* objects, and sort them 
according to `timeCompleted` of the related session:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"SessionDetails"];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"session.timeCompleted" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sort]];
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

(I have assumed that you have an inverse relationship `session` from
*SessionDetails* to *Session*.)

Now you can extract the `timeCompleted` and `averageDistance` value from these objects,
using Key-Value Coding:

```
NSArray *xValues = [result valueForKeyPath:@"session.timeCompleted"];
NSArray *yValues = [result valueForKey:@"averageDistance"];
```

Comment: The only problem I have with this is that averageDistance is a property of SessionDetails.

Comment: @user2480376: OK. The session is related to *many* SessionDetails. Which of the values do you want to display? Or you want the *average* of all averageDistance values?

Comment: I will give you a little background.  In another tab, I have a table view that lists the Sessions with the date in the cell label.  If you click on a cell, you get a grouped table view with the list (repetitions) of all the distanceValues and the averageDistance in another section (these attributes are in SessionDetails).  Basically what I would like to do is plot the averageDistance versus the date for each event.  Is this more clear?

Comment: @user2480376: Not completely. For example, if you have one Session with date "1.1.2000" and that session is related to 3 SessionDetails objects with averageDistance 10, 20, 30: What should the plot show? What would the (x, y) values for the plot be?

Comment: @user2480376: In other words, can there be multiple y-values for one x-value?

Comment: Okay, so say I have 5 points I would like to plot.  This means I would have 5 different Sessions, each with its own averageDistance value.  The x-axis would have the date of the Session and the y-axis would have the averageDistance associated with that Session.  The problem I am having is the two values I want to plot are in different entities and I need to make sure that if I have Session 1.1.2000, I get its averageDistance value and not the average distance for another Session 1.2.2000.

Comment: @user2480376: You don't have **one** averageDistance associated with a session. You have **many** averageDistance associated with a session, because Session<->>SessionDetails is a to-many relationship.

Comment: @user2480376: Is the following correct: You need all (timeCompleted, averageDistance) pairs, sorted by averageDistance?

Comment: I need (timeCompleted, averageDistance) pairs sorted by timeCompleted.  This will allow the graph to show the change in averageDistance over time.

Comment: @user2480376: OK, I have updated the answer. I have actually tested the code with some sample data and it seems to work. I hope that is what you need! - Let me know if you need more information. Otherwise please note that you can "accept" an answer by clicking on the check mark! Perhaps you know that already, but I noticed that you did not accept any answer yet. Accepting an answer marks the problem as solved and gives some reputation points to you and to the author of the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I have one last question though.  Is there any reason why if I log the arrays xValues and yValues I get duplicates of the values?

Comment: 2013-07-18 09:35:27.163 FingerMeasurements_7_17_13[27498:c07] x: (
    "2013-07-18 13:35:20 +0000",
    "2013-07-18 13:35:20 +0000"
)
2013-07-18 09:35:27.163 FingerMeasurements_7_17_13[27498:c07] y: (
    "0.9820583",
    "0.9820583"
)

Comment: @user2480376: There should be exactly one x-Value and one y-Value for each *SessionDetails* objects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work in your case:

```
NSArray *sessions = ... // sorted array of Session objects

for (Session *session in sessions)
{
    NSDate *date = session.timeStamp; // you get the date

    NSSet *detailsSet = session.sessionDetails; // session.(details) or whatever the name of the relation is
    for (SessionDetails *details in detailsSet)
    {
        float averageDistance = details.averageDistance; // you get the average distance
        // collect your (date, averageDistance) pair here
    }
}
```